# How to send static files from server without express

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to build a web application that runs only on pure node js without express or other packages.

I didn't find a good method for sending multiple files connected from the server.
For example, send html,css and js file that are connected.
Now, I can only send the html file.

I have a folder named "design" with 3 files---> index.html,style.css,scipt.js

*I really don't care what method you use, I just want to send more then 1 files connected to the client from the server.

Thanks :) !

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const server = http.createServer((req,res)=>{
    if(req.url == '/')
    {
        const readStream = fs.createReadStream('./design/index.html');
        res.writeHead(200,{'Content-type': 'text/html'});
        readStream.pipe(res);

    }
});

server.listen('3000',()=>console.log("Connected Succesfully"));
```

Comment: Are you trying to send three files for one incoming http request?  Or three separate files for three different incoming requests?

Answer (score 2):

By default, if you were able to serve HTML correctly to the browser, the HTML itself will request any CSS, JavaScript, or asset files that it needs!

The problem is that when HTML requests these files, `/styles.css` for example, the server doesn't know what to do!

That's why you need to set up a request handler for every asset:

```
const server = http.createServer((req,res)=>{
    if(req.url == '/') {
        const readStream = fs.createReadStream('./design/index.html');
        res.writeHead(200,{'Content-type': 'text/html'});
        readStream.pipe(res);

    }

    if (req.url == '/styles.css') {
        const readStream = fs.createReadStream('./design/styles.css');
        res.writeHead(200,{'Content-type': 'text/html'});
        readStream.pipe(res);
    }

    if (req.url == '/script.js') {
        const readStream = fs.createReadStream('./design/script.js');
        res.writeHead(200,{'Content-type': 'text/html'});
        readStream.pipe(res);
    }
});
```

But of course, since this is not very neat, you can do something like this:

```
const readStream = fs.createReadStream(`./design${req.url}`);
```

once, and it will serve all the assets required only using one code block.

Comment: It's nice, but it doesn't happen. I barely found solutions on the Interent

Comment: @Yopi, You are right, I illustrated more about how to fix it.

Comment: Strange... It still send 1 file of html after long time of loading the url

Comment: @Yopi This long time of loading means that the browser is trying to request the other files. Check that the routes are correct, and that the files names are spelled correct. I've used `styles.css` while you are using `style.css` for example!

Comment: @Yopi I tested myself so I'm a bit confident it works.

Comment: @Yopi Would you please give me a feedback about whether it worked or not?